# Ocultar el valor de un input en un formulario html5

Tags: javascript, html5, css

He creado un formulario con html5 pero necesito ocultar el valor insertado en un campo del formulario. ¿Eso es posible? De ser posible, ¿cómo se hace?

El código basicamente es este:

```
<form><input type="text" value=""><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></form>
```

Comment: agrega tu código para poder ser mas específicos al ayudarte, si estas usando un input intenta <input type="password">

Comment: ¿Te refieres a [campos del tipo password](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/password)? esos que escribes y no se ve nada, sólo unos puntitos. `<input type="password">`

Comment: mas menos esa es la idea, pero en realidad quisiera que no se vieran ni los punticos

Comment: Pues si el fondo es blanco, le das el mismo color al texto y no se verá nada. `<input style="color:#fff;">`, aunque si se hace una selección se verá lo que hay escrito, tendrías que o usar los puntitos o inventarte otra cosa para que no vean los códigos de la bomba nuclear que quieres introducir en tus input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Te puedes apoyar de CSS con `color: transparent`

```css
.hidden-text-input {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input class='hidden-text-input' value='abc'>
```